# What do the stars under "can produce" mean in against the storm

Tags: against-the-storm

Does it mean it can produce those goods faster, higher quality or what? Is it worth it to replace buildings with higher starred versions or prioritize going for buildings with new stuff?

So for example should i pick up a lumber mill to replace planks over the starter plank building or go for a bath house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stars correspond to the efficiency of the recipe. Unfortunately I can't find any resources online which specify the exact ratios, but I know the Lumber Mill produces about three times as many planks as the Crude Workstation for a given amount of wood, and does so considerably faster as well. So if you're low on raw materials, the improved buildings are essential. You're usually not low on wood, but planks are so important to have tons and tons of that the Lumber Mill might be worth it anyway (but the Carpenter is even better because it also has other good recipes).

Comment: Isn't Lumber Mill better for planks since it has 3 stars instead of 2 for carpenter?

Comment: Yes, the Lumber Mill is slightly better for planks specifically, but its other two recipes are kind of bad. The Carpenter has three pretty good recipes, and considering that blueprints are so valuable, I'd rather get three useful things out of one blueprint.

Comment: I see, it's kinda hard for me to judge unless I understand the exact ratios. I feel like I would want to specialize the building and then trade for the other 2 or just allow myself to have less of those for this specific playthrough?